# What is this gerund construction called?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

In English the constructing *for* plus a corresponding gerund is often used, usually to identify a motivation for the main action (it seems to be more prevalent in colloquial speech); e.g.:

> I thank you *for helping me*.
>
> I banned him from the bar *for picking fights*.

What is this construction called?

Comment: I don't think this is a distinct construction; we can also say "I thank you *for your help*", "I banned him from the bar *for his role in the fight*".

Comment: Remember that gerunds function as nouns. The construction, then, would be the same one as "Thank you for your help" or "Thank you for the muffins" etc.

Comment: @Robusto That's almost right, but not quite. Gerund ***phrases/clauses*** function as noun phrases, but gerunds themselves function only as verbs (because, in fact, that’s what they are :). So the gerund being a verb takes a direct object in *helping **me*** and in *picking **fights***, and it is only the entire gerund phrase/clause *in toto* which is actually functioning as a noun phrase to allow that constituent to be the object of the preposition.. The distinction may be subtle, and it is often neglected in off-the-cuff explanations to grade-school children, but it is an important one.

Comment: The _for_ element is a preposition phrase headed by "for" with the gerund-participial clauses "helping me" / "picking fights" as its complement. The PPs serve as reason adjuncts in clause structure.

Comment: @tchrist: "Sharing is caring." How are there not two nouns in that sentence?

Comment: @Robusto  Your examples are ambiguous. Verb interpretation can be forced by adverbial premodification, as in "Occasionally sharing is occasionally caring", and noun interpretation by adjectival premodification as in "occasional sharing is occasional caring".

Comment: @BillJ: My example is not ambiguous. Your interpretation of it, which required additional syntactical elements, turns it into something it is not. Absent modifiers, the two gerunds fall firmly into the "noun interpretation" camp.

Comment: @Robusto Really? Then you have to prove it by demonstrating the noun-like properties that "sharing" and "caring" possess.

Comment: Further, I would say that verb interpretation is the more salient interpretation: "To share is to care".